# Angular create reusable component

Tags: angular, input, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I am creating a reusable input type component in Angular 10 with ControlValueAccessor. But my problem is that my variable formControleName is still undefined

I used the class found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eznzw5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcontrol-value-accessor-connector.ts. just adding the decorator @Directiv

My component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp-input',
  templateUrl: './comp-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comp-input.component.scss'],
  providers: [{

    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,     useExisting: forwardRef(() => CompInputComponent),

    multi: true
  },
  {
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CompInputComponent),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class CompInputComponent extends ControlValueAccessorConnector {
  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    super(injector);
  }
```

Call myComponent :

```
<form [formGroup]="simpleForm">
    <app-comp-input formControlName="name"></app-comp-input>
</form
```

I don't understand the problem

Comment: what do you mean by `variable formControleName is still undefined`

Comment: My string formControlName is still undefined. I feel like it doesn’t get the value I pass

Comment: from what you provide in your example `simpleForm.value.name` should contain the value of the input

Comment: here is a correct implementation of `controlValueAcessor` for checkbox by the angular team, that might help you see how this work.

Comment: My problem is that if in my input component in the constructor I make a console.log(this.formControlName) the value is still undefined. The name of the field I want to give is not received by the component

Comment: @JSmith you did not link

Comment: sorry [here it is](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/checkbox_value_accessor.ts)

Comment: The example you give me is just for checkboxes. I want to do something generic that I could use for all my components